# TypeError in Recursive Function (Decimal to Binary)

Tags: python, recursion

all, I have this code that, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to solve this TypeError.

```
def dtobr(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (n % 2) + 10 * dtobr(int(n / 2))
```

I need it to return as a string (project requirement for class). The math is correct, but when I change the last line to

```
return str((n % 2) + 10 * dtobr(int(n / 2)))
```

I get

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'".

I have tried setting `"return (n % 2) + 10 * dtobr(int(n / 2))"` to `x`, setting `y` to `int(x)` and returning `y`, and I've have no clue (and Google isn't offering any solutions that I can try to apply to my problem) what else I can do. Any ideas would be helpful!!

Comment: "I need it to return as a string" why?

Comment: The type error is because you're calling `dtobr` on the result of `dtobr`, and it multiplies with an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `str()` on the return means that all the recursive calls will also return a `str`, so you need to either convert those returns back to a `int`, e.g.:

```
def dtobr(n):
    if n == 0:
        return '0'
    else:
        return str((n % 2) + 10 * int(dtobr(n // 2)))

In []:
dtobr(10)

Out[]:
'1010'
```

Or just use a helper function to do the conversion:

```
def dtobr(n):
    return str(dtobr_(n))

def dtobr_(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (n % 2) + 10 * dtobr_(n // 2)

In []:
dtobr(10)

Out[]:
'1010'
```

But I don't see why just calling `str(dtobr(10))` wouldn't be equally as good.

Note: `//` is integer division so you don't need to `int(n/2)`, `n//2` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
def dtobr(n):
   n = int(n)
   if n == 0:
      return 0
   else:
      return str((n % 2) + 10 * int(dtobr(int(n / 2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions offered so far involve conversions to `str` and `int` and back again.  I don't think that's necessary and we can solve this without `int()` and multiplication:

```
def dtobr(n):
    if n == 0:
        return '0'

    return dtobr(n // 2).lstrip('0') + str(n % 2)
```

The trick is to do the recursion ahead of the current digit, instead of the other way around.  This avoids the conversion back to int and the multiplication by 10.

**EXAMPLE**

```
>>> dtobr(12)
'1100'
>>>
```